# When input is 0 stop taking values

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, int

I need code, that takes inputs from user and then adds them together-simple. But I can't find a way, to take inputs until 0 is pressed and than add the numbers together..
So far, I made it take 10 values, but like I said it needs to be custom.. Thanks for your help.

```
int[] myarray = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myarray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

int a = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    a = a + myarray[j];
}

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Did you try anything? How did it go? Is there a specific reason to keep a record of all the values, or do you only need the sum?

Comment: Im new to this and this is a part of my programing class, so I still know very little.. I tried searching for similar things, but I didn't find it.. If i would have an example i would know how to do it. but sadly I don't :( And yes i only need the sum.

Comment: You don't need "a code", you need "code". :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below is not limited to 10 inputs, you can give as many input as you like

```
int sum=0, input;
do
{
    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    sum += input;
}
while(input != 0);

Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the input before adding it, and [break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) out of the loop if it is 0:

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if(input == 0) 
{
  break;
}

myarray[i] = input;
```

Comment: _Note:_ in the second loop hard-coded `10` should be changed to `myarray.Length` to avoid `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Or better, `foreach` loop should be used.

Comment: @PLB - seeing as both loops have the same length, is that a real concern?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't know the length of the array, I'd recommend using a list.  I've also added a tryparse to cope with dodgy user input.  You can use Sum() on the list to avoid writing out another loop.

```
        IList<int> myList = new List<int>();
        string userInput = "";
        int myInt = 0;

        while (userInput != "0")
        {
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if(Int32.TryParse(userInput, out myInt) && myInt > 0)
            {
                myList.Add(myInt);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(myList.Sum());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Sarwar's solution is more elegant, I focussed on the array rather than the end goal. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have an unknown size array you should use a list.

```
var ls = new List<int>();

    while(true)
    {
        var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if(input == 0) 
            break;

        ls.Add(input);
    }
```

[Lists by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```
while(true)
{
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if(input == 0)
        break;

    //do you math here
}
```